# Can we lazy load data for dropdown while doing inline edit?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am working on inline-editing functionality with [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid).

As per official documentation: [ag-Grid Cell Editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#gsc.tab=0), we can provide dropdown options values while providing column definition `colDef` itself.

```
colDef.cellEditor = 'selectCellEditor';
colDef.cellEditorParams = {
    values: ['English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Portuguese', '(other)']
}
```

What to do when these values are to be fetched from server? i.e. Can we lazy load and then provide `cellEditorParams` values for the dropdown? (I haven't come across any)

Any solution or even direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom editor component having dropdown as template and make HTTP call to load the data for the dropdown.
i.e., while creating `ColDef` for the column,

```
let column: ColDef = {
        headerName: 'Lookup', field: 'FieldName', coldId: 'Id'
        cellEditorFramework: DropdownEditorComponent,
        cellEditorParams: {} // whatever data you want to have in editor component
}
```

In the editor component,

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ICellEditorAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import * as _ from 'underscore';
// import HttpService

@Component({
    template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="selectionChanged()" #dropdown>
        <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
    `
})
```

Component definition:

```
export class DropdownEditorComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp, AfterViewInit {

    private params: any;
    private items: any[];
    private selectedValue: any;
    private selectControl: ElementRef;

    @ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown: ElementRef;

    constructor(private http: HttpService) {
        this.items = [];
    }        
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.selectControl = this.dropdown;
    }

    agInit(params: any): void {
        if(this.items.length == 0) {
            this.params = params;
            this.http.post(url, params)
            // this.http.get(url) // if the call is a GET
                .subscribe(result => {
                    this.items = result;
                    this.selectedValue = _.find(this.items, item => item.label == params.value);
                });
        }
    }

    getValue(): any {
        return this.selectedValue.label;
    }
    isPopup(): boolean {
        return false;
    }
    setValue(value: any): any {
        this.selectedValue = value;
    }
    selectionChanged(): void {
        // whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the http method be get?

Answer (score 0):

can define a function to return array data.

this.opts = ['English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Portuguese', '(other)'];

let column: ColDef = {
headerName: 'Lookup', field: 'FieldName', coldId: 'Id'
cellEditorFramework: DropdownEditorComponent,
cellEditorParams: {
getOptions:（）＝｛
　　　　　　return this.opts;
　　　　　　　　　　　　｝
}
}

export class DropdownEditorComponent implements ICellEditorAngularComp, AfterViewInit {

```
private params: any;
private items: any[];
private selectedValue: any;
private selectControl: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown: ElementRef;

constructor() {
    this.items = [];
}        
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selectControl = this.dropdown;
}

agInit(params: any): void {
    this.items = params.getOptions();
}

getValue(): any {
    return this.selectedValue.label;
}
isPopup(): boolean {
    return false;
}
setValue(value: any): any {
    this.selectedValue = value;
}
selectionChanged(): void {
    // whatever you want to do
}
```

}